# Counting URL in dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset with token and entity columns. In the token column there is a word and also a URL. I want to get the number of URL in token column. but I didn't find suitable source code. What I found is a way to remove the URL. Is there a way to calculate the number of URLs in the dataset? How do I calculate the number of URLs in a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can use the count() fun in the DataFrame class in the Pandas library.
First try importing the Pandas as pd
create a object for Dataframe class
Use the count() with object with necessary parameters.

Comment: can you give an example? I do not understand.